# SharePoint autogenerated JSON formatting and use of operator or field choice not working

Tags: json, sharepoint-online

I did a search on this topic and I am not that JSON familiar, so I thought I'd see if I can find the answer here to my question from the community.

I have a view from a list that I am formatting in SharePoint (SP) that creates some automated JSON.  It simply colors the items based on if the value matches in the generated JSON code.  I am trying to tweak it but having trouble getting the format to come up as a match.

I am trying to use just the one column called Display.  It's a calculated field which concatenates a bunch of string text.

Here is what the generated section of code from SP I am trying to tweak looks like (this is not all of it):

```
{  "operator": "==", 
    "operands": [
    "[$Display]",
     "LOCATED"
    ]
     }, =if(@isSelected == "true" etc...
```

So the formatting will happen if the data in field Display = LOCATED returning true and will apply the formatting.  What I am trying to do, is get some sort of string contains or wild card matching.

The contents of the field Display in the SP list will contain something dynamic and possibly the word LOCATED somewhere in the text.

So ideally I'd like to tweak this code to return true for the formatting if the Display field content said something like  "John Doe LOCATED New York" for example.

if anyone has any ideas how I could solve this that would be great.  Also I was trying another field which is a choice field for exact matching but I couldn't get it to work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add complete JSON to your question? I will have look & suggest the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved, by doing an exact field match instead of wildcarding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).